# Copy one database to another using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to copy a database using SQLAlchemy. The first attempt was:

```
from from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from urls import engine_urls 

engine1 = create_engine(engine_urls[0])
engine2 = create_engine(engine_urls[1])

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine1)
tables = metadata.tables
metadata.create_all(engine2)


Session1 = sessionmaker(bind=engine1)

from sqlalchemy import insert
 
with Session1.begin() as session:
    for key in tables:
        table_object = tables[key]
        for row in session.query(table_object):
            s = insert(table_object).\
                values(**dict(zip(row.keys(), row))) 
            engine2.execute(s)
```

But this code does not work since the order in which inserts are done is arbitrary and this violates FK constraints. For example, inserting a child before a parent will cause such a violation. How could I achieve this task? Is there a part of the framework that would do this easily? I can't find it.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.sorted_tables

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use. Works well.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, event
from sqlalchemy.sql import sqltypes

#  Requires SQLALCHEMY 1.4+

src_engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydb.sqlite")
src_metadata = MetaData(bind=src_engine)
exclude_tables = ('sqlite_master', 'sqlite_sequence', 'sqlite_temp_master')

tgt_engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://@localhost/ngas")
tgt_metadata = MetaData(bind=tgt_engine)

@event.listens_for(src_metadata, "column_reflect")
def genericize_datatypes(inspector, tablename, column_dict):
   column_dict["type"] = column_dict["type"].as_generic(allow_nulltype=True)     

tgt_conn = tgt_engine.connect()
tgt_metadata.reflect()

# drop all tables in target database
for table in reversed(tgt_metadata.sorted_tables):
   if table.name not in exclude_tables:
      print('dropping table =', table.name)
      table.drop()

# # Delete all data in target database
# for table in reversed(tgt_metadata.sorted_tables):
#    table.delete()

tgt_metadata.clear()
tgt_metadata.reflect()
src_metadata.reflect()

# create all tables in target database
for table in src_metadata.sorted_tables:
   if table.name not in exclude_tables:
      table.create(bind=tgt_engine)

# refresh metadata before you can copy data
tgt_metadata.clear()
tgt_metadata.reflect()

# Copy all data from src to target
for table in tgt_metadata.sorted_tables:
   src_table = src_metadata.tables[table.name]
   stmt = table.insert()
   for index, row in enumerate(src_table.select().execute()):
      print("table =", table.name, "Inserting row", index)
      stmt.execute(row._asdict())
```

Comment: This does,'t work anymore in SQLAlchemy 2.0++ . You will get the error "TypeError: MetaData.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'" . See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html . It's not directly obvious how to update the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is fixed version (for SQLAlchemy 2.0+) of @Monty's answer:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.sql import sqltypes


src_engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydb.sqlite")
src_metadata = MetaData()
exclude_tables = ("sqlite_master", "sqlite_sequence", "sqlite_temp_master")

tgt_engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://@localhost/ngas")
tgt_metadata = MetaData()


@event.listens_for(src_metadata, "column_reflect")
def genericize_datatypes(inspector, tablename, column_dict):
    column_dict["type"] = column_dict["type"].as_generic(allow_nulltype=True)


src_conn = src_engine.connect()
tgt_conn = tgt_engine.connect()
tgt_metadata.reflect(bind=tgt_engine)

# drop all tables in target database
for table in reversed(tgt_metadata.sorted_tables):
    if table.name not in exclude_tables:
        print("dropping table =", table.name)
        table.drop(bind=tgt_engine)

# # Delete all data in target database
# for table in reversed(tgt_metadata.sorted_tables):
#    table.delete()

tgt_metadata.clear()
tgt_metadata.reflect(bind=tgt_engine)
src_metadata.reflect(bind=src_engine)

# create all tables in target database
for table in src_metadata.sorted_tables:
    if table.name not in exclude_tables:
        table.create(bind=tgt_engine)

# refresh metadata before you can copy data
tgt_metadata.clear()
tgt_metadata.reflect(bind=tgt_engine)

# Copy all data from src to target
for table in tgt_metadata.sorted_tables:
    src_table = src_metadata.tables[table.name]
    stmt = table.insert()
    for index, row in enumerate(src_conn.execute(src_table.select())):
        print("table =", table.name, "Inserting row", index)
        tgt_conn.execute(stmt.values(row))

tgt_conn.commit()
src_conn.close()
tgt_conn.close()
```

Comment: haven't you faced with problem in tables with mutually dependent foreign key constraints? because of unresolved cycles in sorted_tables i can't insert anything((

Comment: Never tried that. But why would you have mutually dependent foreign keys, instead of M2M?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone had difficulties executing the proposed
routine as a solution because "stmt.execute(row._asdict())"
generates an error in version 1.4, here is an alternative
that I successfully produced:

```
# Copy all data from src to target
for table in tgt_metadata.sorted_tables:
    src_table = src_metadata.tables[table.name]
    for index, row in enumerate(src_table.select().execute()):
        print("table =", table.name, "Inserting row", index, '>>', dict(row))
        stmt = table.insert().values(row._asdict())
        tgt_conn.execute(stmt)
    tgt_conn.commit()
```