# auto increment sequence issue, while data insertion, after copying tables with data from one postgres to other postgres using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am copying tables with data from one postgres to other postgres  using SQLAlchemy and python.

I looked into below answers and created a script

[Copy one database to another using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70392123/copy-one-database-to-another-using-sqlalchemy)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, event
from sqlalchemy.sql import sqltypes
import traceback


src_engine = create_engine("postgresql://user1:mypass@myip1:2025/mydb?options=-c search_path=public")
src_metadata = MetaData(bind=src_engine)


tgt_engine = create_engine("postgresql://user2:mypass@myip2:2025/newdb?options=-c search_path=public")
tgt_metadata = MetaData(bind=tgt_engine)


@event.listens_for(src_metadata, "column_reflect")
def genericize_datatypes(inspector, tablename, column_dict):
    column_dict["type"] = column_dict["type"].as_generic(allow_nulltype=True)


tgt_conn = tgt_engine.connect()
tgt_metadata.reflect()


src_metadata.reflect()


for table in src_metadata.sorted_tables:
   table.create(bind=tgt_engine)


# refresh metadata before you can copy data
tgt_metadata.clear()
tgt_metadata.reflect()

# # Copy all data from src to target
for table in tgt_metadata.sorted_tables:
    src_table = src_metadata.tables[table.name]
    stmt = table.insert()
    temp_list = []
    source_table_count = src_engine.connect().execute(f"select count(*) from {table.name}").fetchall()
    current_row_count = 0

    for index, row in enumerate(src_table.select().execute()):
        temp_list.append(row._asdict())
        if len(temp_list) == 2500:
            stmt.execute(temp_list)
            current_row_count += 2500
            print(f"table = {table.name}, inserted {current_row_count} out of {source_table_count[0][0]}")
            temp_list = []
    if len(temp_list) > 0:
        stmt.execute(temp_list)
        current_row_count += len(temp_list)
        print(f"table = {table.name}, inserted {current_row_count} out of {source_table_count[0][0]}")
    print(f'source table "{table.name}": {source_table_count}')
    print(f'target table "{table.name}": {tgt_engine.connect().execute(f"select count(*) from {table.name}").fetchall()}')
```

Sequence copied from source db to target db have below script

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.my_table_request_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 2147483647
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.my_table_request_id_seq
    OWNER TO my_user;
```

Everything is working fine, table schema is copied, data is copied but the auto increment column of each table starts with 1 instead of last incremented value, due to which i am getting an error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` while inserting new data.

I do I solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the working changes for sequence issue.Below is the full code, which copies tables with data from one postgres database to other postgres database using python and sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, event
from sqlalchemy.sql import sqltypes
import traceback


src_engine = create_engine("postgresql://user1:mypass@myip1:2025/mydb?options=-c search_path=public")
src_metadata = MetaData(bind=src_engine)


tgt_engine = create_engine("postgresql://user2:mypass@myip2:2025/newdb?options=-c search_path=public")
tgt_metadata = MetaData(bind=tgt_engine)


@event.listens_for(src_metadata, "column_reflect")
def genericize_datatypes(inspector, tablename, column_dict):
    column_dict["type"] = column_dict["type"].as_generic(allow_nulltype=True)


tgt_metadata.reflect()


src_metadata.reflect()


for table in src_metadata.sorted_tables:
   table.create(bind=tgt_engine)


# refresh metadata before you can copy data
tgt_metadata.clear()
tgt_metadata.reflect()

# Copy all data from src to target
for table in tgt_metadata.sorted_tables:
    src_table = src_metadata.tables[table.name]
    stmt = table.insert()
    temp_list = []
    with src_engine.connect() as src_conn:
        source_table_count = src_conn.execute(f"select count(*) from {table.name}").fetchall()
    current_row_count = 0

    for index, row in enumerate(src_table.select().execute()):
        temp_list.append(row._asdict())
        if len(temp_list) == 2500:
            stmt.execute(temp_list)
            current_row_count += 2500
            print(f"table = {table.name}, inserted {current_row_count} out of {source_table_count[0][0]}")
            temp_list = []
    if len(temp_list) > 0:
        stmt.execute(temp_list)
        current_row_count += len(temp_list)
        print(f"table = {table.name}, inserted {current_row_count} out of {source_table_count[0][0]}")

    ###################### code for sequence restart: start ##############################

    with tgt_engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True) as tgt_conn:
        # getting sequence list
        sequence_list_data = tgt_conn.execute(f"SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';").fetchall()
        sequence_list = [sequence[0] for sequence in sequence_list_data]

        sequence_to_alter = ""
        for sequence in sequence_list:
            if sequence.startswith(table.name):
                # getting sequence name for the given table
                sequence_to_alter = sequence
                break
        if sequence_to_alter:
            # getting column name from sequence name, usually sequence nameis: {tableName}_{columnName}_{seq}, example course_student_id_seq
            new = sequence_to_alter.replace(f"{table.name}_", "")
            sequence_column_name = new.replace("_seq", "")

            # getting last generated sequence id for the table
            last_id = tgt_conn.execute(f"select max({sequence_column_name}) from {table.name}").fetchall()[0][0]

            # restarting the sequence id with last_id+1, so that sequence begins with last generated id + 1
            alter_sequence_query = f"ALTER SEQUENCE {sequence_to_alter} RESTART WITH {last_id + 1};"

            tgt_conn.execute(alter_sequence_query)

            # setting the owner for the sequence to owner needed to be
            tgt_conn.execute(f"ALTER SEQUENCE {sequence_to_alter} OWNER TO my_owner_name")

    ###################### code for sequence restart: end ##############################

    print(f'source table "{table.name}": {source_table_count}')
    with tgt_engine.connect() as tgt_conn:
        print(f'target table "{table.name}": {tgt_conn.execute(f"select count(*) from {table.name}").fetchall()}')
```

In case of any query or correction, please do let me know.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is due to the fact that you are directly inserting in the target column without using the insert.

e.g. in the source database you have a table like the following with the column `id` being the incremental one

```
+------+------------+
|  id  | name       |
+------+------------+
|  1   | test       |
|  2   | test2      |
+------+------------+
```

When this is copied to the target database, it's directly inserted as

```
INSERT INTO TBL_NAME VALUES (1, 'test');
INSERT INTO TBL_NAME VALUES (2, 'test2');
```

without using the sequence.
Possibly a fix would be, once finished the copy, to alter the sequence and set it to the max `id` number found in the source database.

Comment: Exactly that is the case. I am thinking for the same solution i.e to set sequence to last incremented number after insertion. but I don't know what to add in script, manually iIcan but its not feasible, since there are n number of tables. can you please help me with a code which updates the sequence number, after second for loop(insertion of data) is completed.